# SQL syntax error starting at '@'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mySQL query that is getting stuck when I run a string containing '@'. I have tried htmlentities() and htmlspecialchars() to no avail. Here's what I'm running:

```
    $name=$_POST['name'];
$first=$_POST['first'];
$last=$_POST['last'];
$bio=htmlentities($_POST['bio']);
$email=htmlentities($_POST['email']);
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$date=date("m/d/y");
$bd=date('m-d-y',strtotime($_POST['month'].$_POST['date'].$_POST['year']));
$qer="insert into everything (user,first,last,bio,email,pass,date,bd) values ($name,$first,$last,$bio,$email,$pass,$date,$bd)";
if(!(mysql_query($qer,$con))){
    echo "no qer";
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Here is the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   '@re5yhgr5tyhrtyhr5tyr5tyhrt,test@first.com,pass,12/13/12,01-01-70)'
>   at line 1

I was first trying it just in my email parameter, but I now know it has trouble no matter where it is. >:|

I'm assuming "line 1" is the first line of sql since my actual line 1 is ""...

Sorry if this is obvious, thanks in advance!

Comment: i like that table name, "everything"

Comment: **Please read:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php

Answer (score 3):

when inserting a value with a data type of `string`, it should be *enclosed with single quote*. (*Also for Date, Time, DateTime and other as long as it is not numeric*)

```
$qer="insert into everything (user, first, last, bio, email, pass, date, bd) 
      values ('$name', '$first', '$last', ...)";
```

but the query above is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below to learn how to prevent from `SQL Injection`

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @KuyaJohn Great point about SQL Injection. PHP beginners tend to build sites that could be taken down in a second by a malicious coder.

Comment: since i'd rather not switch my stuff to sqli or pdo, would mysql_real_escape_string() work fine for this?     edit: nvm...

Answer (score 2):

Try: Add apostrophe (') in the fields that are of type varchar, char or date.

```
 ...values ('$name','$first','$last','$bio','$email','$pass','$date','$bd')...
```

Comment: While this does answer the question, it will also leave the code wide open to SQL injection attacks. At minimum, use mysql_real_escape_string on everything before inserting in into the database query string, or even better use PDO or mysqli, which are safe, efficient, and don't require quotes.

Comment: @Anton `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't fully prevent your from sql injection, see here: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/5741264#5741264)

Comment: @KuyaJohn You're absolutely correct. There are some characters that could bypass mysql_real_escape_string and allow injection. I just didn't want to overwhelm the asker since they're just starting out :)

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap your args of insert sql within string, like `"test@first.com"`

Comment: This misses the point. The OP should be using prepared statements.